# Is there a command line equivalent of Sigverif.exe?

Tags: windows, scripting

The windows XP sigverif tool is useful for identifying non-signed executables, but does not seem to be amenable to scripting -- is there a command line equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a direct command line equivalent, but there are a couple of things that could get you close.

First, `driverquery.exe` has an argument`/si` that will tell you the signed status of the drivers. It also has an argument `/fo csv` that will dump the output to CSV. The weird part of using this command is that if you use the `/si` argument, you can't get the full path to the driver file (and if you use the `/v` option to get the full path, you can't get the signed status.

Second, if you want to go down the PowerShell path, you could use the `Get-AuthenicodeSignature` cmdlet. This one is weird because you have to pass a driver path into the cmdlet, so you need to build the driver list yourself. You can get that from WMI though, so something like this may suit your needs:

```
Get-WmiObject -class win32_systemdriver |  foreach-object { get-authenticodesignature $_.pathname }
```

Answer (score 3):

I've used sysinternals sigcheck.exe:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897441.aspx

---

Sigcheck v1.66 - File version and signature viewer
Copyright (C) 2004-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

usage: sigcheck [-a][-h][-i][-e][-n][[-s]|[-v]|[-m]][-q][-r][-u][-c catalog file]

-a     Show extended version information

-c     Look for signature in the specified catalog file

-e     Scan executable images only (regardless of their extension)

-h     Show file hashes

-i     Show catalog name and image signers

-m     Dump manifest

-n     Only show file version number

-q     Quiet (no banner)

-r     Check for certificate revocation

-s     Recurse subdirectories

-u     Show unsigned files only

-v     Csv output

---

Example output:

c:\windows\system32\acledit.dll:

```
    Verified:       Signed

    Signing date:   19:07 04/13/2008

    Publisher:      Microsoft Corporation

    Description:    Access Control List Editor

    Product:        Microsoft« Windows« Operating System

    Version:        5.1.2600.0

    File version:   5.1.2600.0 (xpclient.010817-1148)
```

Rob

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried this myself, but I believe signtool has a command line option to verify signatures.